# Add value of type B to type A of same org_id

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sum, window-functions

I have a table like this

```
ORG_ID  TYPE  VALUE
1        A     20
1        B     30
1        C     10
2        B     60
```

Now I want to select values from this table for each org_id, type but for type A i want to add value of type B of same org_id to type A. My query should return this

```
VALUE
50
30
10
60
```

In this case, when ORG_ID is 1 and TYPE is 'A', I have to add that organization's type B value, which is 30. But I do not need to add the last value because that belongs to another organization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
    case when type = 'A'
        then value + max(case when type = 'B' then value else 0 end) over(partition by org_id) 
        else value 
    end as new_value
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e16c418c7526083469afdd6865076a00)**:

```
ORG_ID | TYPE | VALUE | NEW_VALUE
-----: | :--- | ----: | --------:
     1 | A    |    20 |        50
     1 | B    |    30 |        30
     1 | C    |    10 |        10
     2 | B    |    60 |        60
```

Answer (score 1):

A left join should do the job:

```sql
SELECT    a.id, a.type, a.value + COALESCE(b.value, 0)
FROM      mytable a
LEFT JOIN mytable b ON a.type = 'A' AND b.type = 'B' AND a.org_id = b.org_id
```